# How can I change my name using command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there any command in Minecraft where I can change my username in the chat, tab and my name tag above my skin?
And no I'm not noob, I know I can change it on mojangs service, what I mean is like I'm creating a minigame using command blocks and someone is Herobrine then their display name will change to Herobrine. (The UUID is still the same for this player)

Comment: This is not possible in Vanilla Minecraft, but I'm sure that plugins like *Essentials* have commands that are usable in command blocks that change your name. (They don't actually change your global username, but rather act as a nickname on the server you are playing on.)

Comment: @GiantTree Essentials commands are, last I heard, not usable in command blocks. However, they can easily be used ingame: `/nick <nickname>`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no command to change a player's name.

---

As a workaround, you could fake it by hiding the player's name whilst teleporting a named entity onto them.

To hide a player's name tag, put them on a separate team and change the `nametagVisibility` option:

```
/team add HerobrineTeam
/team modify HerobrineTeam nametagVisibility never
```

Then summon a named entity, such as a marker armorstand:

```
/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:'"Herobrine"',CustomNameVisible:1b,Marker:1b,Invisible:1b}
```

You can teleport that entity to the player on a clock with something like:

```
/execute at @p[team=HerobrineTeam] run tp @e[type=armor_stand,name=Herobrine] ~ ~1.7 ~
```

Comment: That's a great work around for something so useful.

Comment: Problem, the armorstand spawns in the ground, under my foots, why?

Comment: @MinecraftDoge Teleport it upwards to the offset you want.

Comment: You can also spawn them directly at the player using /execute, if you're familiar with that. Not sure if it's the case, but it might be actually cleaner to repeatedly kill the armor stand and spawn a new one at the player's location. Probably depends on the case which one is better.

Comment: Will this cause lag?