# How do you give yoursefl a 'nickname' in chat or above the player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc

I want to make a role play like some youtubers, but i do  not know how to give other people nicknames. I really need help a.s.a.p and thanks for your help and time.

Comment: check this [answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/219191/how-can-i-change-my-name-using-command-blocks)

Answer (score 1):

This is done using a serverside plugin. The plugin that I know of would use the command /nick *player* *nickname* to do it, but i couldnt tell you what it is unfortunately, I never saw the name of it. However, if you're trying to do this in singleplayer or a LAN server, I do not believe it is possible, unless a mod exists specifically for this. --- EDIT

Look in the comments below, Alex posted a helpful comment!

Comment: Either Bukkit, Spigot or BungeeCord.